# Show that $x^{2}-6y^{2}=523$ has infinitely many integral solutions

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I want to show that $x^2-6y^2=523$  has infinitely many solutions. For the special case $x^2-dy^2=1$, I know what I need to do. I can get the result by using continued fractions. Also, in the kinds of $x^2-dy^2=m$ for some examples, I can say that there is no solution using modulo prime $p$. But in general, I'm not sure how to find the solution set for $ax^{2}+by^{2}+c=0$ where $a,b,c\in \mathbf{Z}$.

I would appreciate if you can help me with this question or direct it to a resource that can help.

Comment: The general question you ask at the end turns out to be quite a difficult problem in general. In the most general case whether a prime $p$ may be written as $ax^2 + by^2 = p$ boils down to asking about the splitting behaviour of a prime $p$ in the Hilbert Class Field of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ where $D$ is the discriminant of $ax^2 + by^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a twist on Pell's equation in this case. The [fundamental Pell solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#The_smallest_solution_of_Pell_equations) for $D=6$ is $(x,y)=(5,2).$ So all positive solutions to $$a^2-6b^2=1$$ are given by $$a_k+b_k \sqrt{6}=(5+2\sqrt{6})^k$$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}_{+}.$ Here's the fun part: since $(x,y)=(23,1)$ is a solution to $$x^2-6y^2 = 523$$ (found by trying out smaller values of $x$ or $y$ and seeing if the other variable turns out to be an integer), a solution is given by $$x_k + y_k\sqrt{6}=(23+\sqrt{6})(a_k+b_k \sqrt{6})$$ for each positive integer $k.$ It is easy to prove that these are all solutions because if $a^2-6b^2=1$ then
$$(23+\sqrt{6})(a+b\sqrt{6}) = (23a+6b)+(23b+a)\sqrt{6}$$
and
\begin{align*}
(23a+6b)^2-6(23b+a)^2 &= 23^2 (a^2-6b^2) - 6(a^2-6b^2)\\
&= 23^2-6\\
&=523.
\end{align*}

This does not necessarily find all solutions, but you do get infinitely many since they are monotonically increasing in some sense. You can read what [Keith Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/pelleqn2.pdf) has written about finding all solutions.

Comment: I understood the idea very well. I will read the paper you said to see more details. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @TuğbaYesin  here Favst displays the process beginning with $(23,1).$ You get every solution if you do the same process beginning with $(23,-1).$  The reason that just two beginning "seed" points suffice is that 523 is prime. I recommend Weissman,       https://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-105/

Answer (score 3):

$(23, 1)$ is a solution.

If $(x, y)$ is a solution, then $(5x + 12y, 2x + 5y)$ is also a solution.

Comment: it’s better if you show your analysis ( some key details ) that leads to the answer.

Comment: @DeepSea I would like to, but without any context I'm not sure whether the OP is supposed to know the ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt 6]$ or any of the algebraic number theory backgrounds.

Comment: Then I would suppose that the preferred method is to leave a comment inquiring that instead of writing an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but actually I am curious about the process that continues after finding a solution. Also, finding the first solution isn't always that easy, right?

Comment: @TuğbaYesin The first question is easier to answer: simply multiply $x + y\sqrt 6$ by $5 + 2\sqrt 6$. The second question (i.e. finding the first solution) is more complicated. In this simple case, just try every value of $y$, starting from $0$.